# How to issue commands to pdb?

Tags: python, debugging

I have been trying to use pdb to debug my Python program, however whenever I get to this screen

[image]

I don't know what to do. Usually when I use pdb I just type commands after (Pdb), but when I try to do the same in the buffer above like

```
(Pdb) n
```

It gives me "n is undefined" in the minibuffer. I've tried to look at tutorials for using pdb in emacs specifically such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324758/debugging-python-programs-in-emacs) and [here](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/debuggers.html), but I still can't figure out where to type the commands. When I used an IDE I just typed the commands like I tried above, but here it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure the solution must be obvious, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to run `pdb` as a compilation process... the buffer created by `M-x compile` or similar is typically read-only, so typing anything into it will not result in changing the text of the buffer. How did you get to running `pdb` in this way? I normally just run my Python scripts from shell with `python -m pdb script.py [script arguments]`, but there should also be a way to run it from GUD.

Comment: Also, take a look at this project: https://github.com/realgud/realgud it seems to have nice integration with PDB.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that you can't run pdb by compiling. I think I tried using the shell before but I got stuck with that too, but It seems that using `C-c C-p` and then `C-c C-c`  along with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` works. I was confused since I thought `C-c C-p` would run the program, but it seems that it only starts the Python process. I also tried realgud but I also couldn't seem to get that to work. I suppose I will have to chalk that up to new user error since I am still learning how this whole thing works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure where you're at with this but the following works for me:

```
M-x pdb
```

It prompts for your program file and starts the debugger.

I didn't have `pdb` installed on my system so I had to create this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167614/python-mode-in-emacs-no-such-file-or-directory-pdb) ... it also has a windows version)

```
cat > ~/bin/pdb << EOF
#!/bin/sh
exec python -m pdb "$@"
EOF
chmod +x ~/bin/pdb
```